# php array key not found if key is a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I think this isn't supposed to happen, but I can't find why this isn't working. I'm checking user input for duplicate choices. `$into_fields_count` is an array of database fields mapped to the number of times selected by the user (db field => count), `$into_fields_dupes` gathers the duplicates.

```
    foreach ( $into_fields_count as $field => $count )
    {
        if ( $count > 1 ) $into_fields_dupes[$field] = $count;
    }
    if ( $into_fields_dupes )
    {
        // construct error message
        $error = ERR_MAP_DUPLICATES;
        foreach ( $into_fields_dupes as $field => $count )
        {
            $error .= "\n" . 'Datenbankfeld "' .  $artikel_fields[$field] . '" wurde ' . $count . ' mal gewählt.';
        }
        $error .= "\nBitte korrigieren Sie den Fehler vor dem Import!";
        throw new Exception($error);
    }
```

The problem is using the same variable `$field` in both `foreach` arrays. In the second loop the attempt to get the value for `$artikel_fields[$field]` throws up the notice

```
Notice: Undefined index: bestell_nr in /my/file/path...
```

However, testing for `$artikel_fields['bestell_nr']` after this code does find the key. Obviously the variable contains the right string in the questionable line.

I can fix this very easily by changing the variable name in the second loop, but I want to get my head around what's happening here. Can you tell me why the code doesn't work?

Comment: Possibly some hidden character? What does `var_dump($field)` show?

Comment: Do you have to know the duplicate entries? Why not just unset them? Also what is the array $artikel_fields? Was it filled out in some other place?

Comment: **Thank You!** @Marc B - Eclipse debugger shows the value of $field has length 11 - there's a space before it: ' bestell_nr', so changing variables wouldn't help.

Comment: @Magic Lasso: I want to tell the user about the error so he can correct it. $artikel_fields was filled up before; it contains the db-field => display-name values.

Comment: Can you tell me how the $into_fields_count and $artikel_fields variables are filled (a var_dump will suffice). Also, as a habit, it's better not to simply start filling an array without declaring a variable is an array. Then, later, don't simply put the statement 'if ($arr)', but count the values 'if (count($arr))' or 'if (count($arr) > 0)'.

Comment: @Battle_707, those variables are declared as arrays in the rest of the code. There's really no sense in showing you the contents of the arrays; the problem was solved - I included the spaces by mistake. Thanks for the if($array) tip though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as stated is misleading. The problem with finding the key in the array was not that the same variable name was used in the two `foreach` loops; the reason is that the key searched for had inadvertently been prefixed with a space character, and the additional space was not seen while debugging.

An answer to the question could be: If such an obscure "error" occurs, check for hidden characters in the key you are searching for. Actually @Marc B answered the question in the first comment.

I will leave the title as is, so that someone else with this issue can find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the excellent suggestions of Marc B and Magic Lasso, you can also use the PHP function `trim` to remove white space characters from a string.  [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is a link to the PHP manual entry on `trim`.

Also, you can use one of the offshoots of this methodology to trim the whitespace from just the beginning of the string:
[ltrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

Or you can trim whitespace at the end of the string using:
[rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Comment: Thanks for the trim() tip, though I would rather prevent character injection by using correct code than trimming 'just in case.' The space was added not due to user input but by me!